# Anti Alias UIImage in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, antialiasing

I have a UIImageView on the screen, and the backgroundcolor of that UIImageView is blue - so a blue square.

I have a UIImage which is a white shape on a transparent background.  This is just two colours - transparent and white.  No anti aliasing in the image so it looks jagged.

What I'd like to do is put the image in the imageview, but have it anti aliased.  If I just put it in the image view simply with

```
myimageview.image=myImage;
```

Then I get a blue square with my white shape in it, but it does not anti alias ie blend the white into the blue so it looks nice and smooth.  I just get the image on the blue background which is I guess what it should do.

So my question is, is it possible add the image into the uiimageview, but have it use anti aliasing?

Thanks

Comment: You need to blur the image slightly, which you can do with a CIFilter (applying a Gaussian blur to an image is equivalent to rendering the image with anti-aliasing). The question is, why aren't you rendering the square with anti-aliasing to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

No. At least not without some complex code that manipulates the image data. The image you are starting with is simply lacking the detail necessary for a smooth display.

However, you might want to consider drawing your image at run time. Below is a sample of a drawing method and an easy way to convert that into a UIImage. This has several advantages, including smaller file size, and optimal resolution on any iOS devices.

There are tools to help generate code like. PaintCode is my preferred tool.

```
static UIImage* _imageOfStarShape = nil;

+ (void)drawStarShape
{
    //// Star Drawing
    UIBezierPath* starPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
    [starPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(50, 22.5)];
    [starPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(58.99, 35.62)];
    [starPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(74.25, 40.12)];
    [starPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(64.55, 52.73)];
    [starPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(64.99, 68.63)];
    [starPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(50, 63.3)];
    [starPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(35.01, 68.63)];
    [starPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(35.45, 52.73)];
    [starPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(25.75, 40.12)];
    [starPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(41.01, 35.62)];
    [starPath closePath];
    [UIColor.whiteColor setFill];
    [starPath fill];
}

+ (UIImage*)imageOfStarShape
{
    if (_imageOfStarShape)
        return _imageOfStarShape;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(100, 100), NO, 0.0f);
    [ThisClass drawStarShape];

    _imageOfStarShape = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return _imageOfStarShape;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just create a higher quality image file?

Comment: Possibly, but you would end up maintaining multiple resolutions for different devices and have a larger file size. With the right tools, creating these drawing methods is arguably easier than including bitmapped images.

Comment: Given that the OP didn't specify what the image looks like, how do we know whether it would be easy or difficult to draw?

Comment: He stated that it is a white shape on a clear background and is a one-bit image. To me, that sounds pretty easy.

Comment: So, if say it was a silhouette of a human face, that would be easy? Just sayin'.

Comment: Well, for the project I am working on now, I brought in an image of an elephant. The tool I used generated the Objective-C drawing method and allows me to scale and color the image at runtime. But I guess it all comes down to the skill of the developer and available tools. This answer solves the problem of putting an antialiased UIImage into a UIImageView. If you have a better solution, propose it in another answer.

Comment: Wow, that's impressive! Didn't realize PaintCode was that sophisticated.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input.  Seems there is no simple way of doing this.  I'll probably just start with a better source image in the first place!